# Why is System.JobId sometimes not unique?

Tags: azure-devops

I have several Azure DevOps release pipelines. I have a step which copies all my deployment scripts to a unique and one-time Azure Storage blob container, named for the release variable System.JobId. This is so that I can guarantee that whenever I run a release, I am always using up-to-date scripts and it shouldn't be possible to be referring to old copies, regardless of any unpredictable error conditions. The container is deleted at the end of a release.

The [documentation for System.JobId](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) states:

> A unique identifier for a single attempt of a single job.

However, intermittently and at random, sometimes my pipeline fails on the blob copy step with:

```
2020-03-30T19:28:55.6860345Z [2020/03/30 19:28:55][ERROR] [path-to-my-file]: No input is received when user needed to make a choice among several given options.
```

I can't directly see that this is because the blob already exists, but when I navigate to the storage account, I can see that a container exists and it contains all the files I would expect it to. Most other times when the pipeline runs successfully, the container is gone at this point.

Why does it seem that *sometimes* the JobId is reused, when the documentation says it is unique? I am not redeploying the same release stage on multiple attempts to trigger this problem. Each occurrence is a new release.

Answer (score 1):

> Why does it seem that sometimes the JobId is reused, when the
>   documentation says it is unique?

Sorry for the mis-leading that our document guide.

The **unique** only represent **relative to current pipeline**, instead of the complete system.

Take a simple sample, there has 2 pipeline: `p1`, `p2`, and each pipeline has 2 jobs: `job1`, `job2`. In pipeline `p1`, the `job id` of `job1` is **unique** and other jobs will not has same `job id` value.

**BUT** in meanwhile, the corresponding `job id` value in pipeline `p2` is same with the one in pipeline `p1`. Also, it will has same value even after re-run pipeline `p1`.

To use your words, this job id value will re-use in a new pipeline execution, including one pipeline re-run.

Comment: I see. Could you suggest what random variable could I use instead that is genuinely unique per run?

Comment: @TomW, If you want a random value, I'm afraid there's no build-in variables can achieve. But unique is possible, consider to use Release.DeploymentID or Release.ReleaseId, these two are all unique in system.